# sed command for substituting string with / characters

Tags: sed

I am trying to substitute `name=src.` with `name=Web/` in my xml file using the `sed` command:

```
sed -i 's/name=src\./name=WebUi\//g' coverage.xml
```

but it gives an error.

Can anyone please provide an idea on the `sed` command?

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: wrt `it gives an error` - what error? When you take your car to a mechanic to be repaired you probably don't just drop it of and say `it gives an error`, I'd hope you tell her the error message/display icon/other symptoms. That's the best way to get help here too. Since your script is fine the problems either a missing required backup file name for your sed version or you have an issue elsewhere in your code around the call to sed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `/` appears as part of the text, whether in the regex or replacement, use a character other than `/` in the `s///` notation (I chose `|`, but you can use any character that doesn't appear in the regex or replacement; a control character such as <kbd>Control-A</kbd> can often be effective and safe):

```
sed command sed -i 's|name=src\.|name=WebUi/|g' coverage.xml
```

Note that the `-i` option written like that only works with GNU `sed`; with BSD or macOS `sed`, you'd need `-i ''` instead.  Using `-i.bak` works the same with both but leaves a backup file that should be removed.

It always worries me when I see people with broken `sed` scripts doing an in-place alter.  You shouldn't think of using the `-i` option until you're confident the script works.

---

On review, I'm surprised that the original `'s/name=src\./name=WebUi\//g'` didn't work — the backslash before the slash should have been correct.

Comment: I expect it's the missing backup file name that's the problem, nothing to do with the actual script since it's fine as written. If the OP had posted the error message that might have been immediately obvious.

Comment: @EdMorton: I suspect so too.  I didn't hear back from the OP about which system he was using.  At one point there was a comment about "`c` not followed by backslash" as the error, which would be consistent with BSD/macOS `sed` treating the script as the backup suffix and the file name (`coverage.xml`) as the 'script' with a `c` not followed by a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
sed 's/name=src/name=Web/g' filename.txt
```

Comment: this will only replace src with Web. I want to replace src. with Web/